# Searching for a String in an Array and returning the position

Tags: java, arrays, equals

Hi I'm a complete newbie on programming and I try to search for a certain `String` in an array. When it's found the method should return the index but if the `String` is not found it should return -1.

```
public int poitionOfWord(String testWord) {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
        if (wordArray[i].equals(testWord)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

would this method return always -1 or would it actually terminate when finding a word and would return i.

Comment: What is the value of `testWord` passed and what are the contents of `wordArray`

Comment: It will terminate as soon as there's a match, i.e. it will *short-circuit*.

Comment: You have to make sure the content of `testWord` is actually stored in `wordArray` on an arbitrary position. Otherwise, you code looks ok and should meet the requirements.

Comment: Your code looks good. One way of answering your question is running your code...

Comment: Your code is fine. It will return the position of the item if found or -1 if not found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your method is correct and it will return the index in case it finds a match else if it doesn't find the match, it will come out of loop and return -1.

Just to make code crisp and concise, you can use something like this,

```
public static String[] wordArray = new String[]{"a", "b"};
public static int poitionOfWord(String testWord) {
    return Arrays.asList(wordArray).indexOf(testWord);
}
```

Then test it with some code,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(poitionOfWord("a"));
    System.out.println(poitionOfWord("z"));
}
```

This prints,

```
1
-1
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, when your function reaches a return statement, it will terminate and return the given value.